# Share button in Facebook iOS webview iframe does not work

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview, share-button

I'm having problem with share button on a webpage. The article holds an iframe with the content and a share button. Everything works fine with iOS safari but when the content gets shared to Facebook and a user opens up the web page in fb iOS app, built in web view the share button in the iframe does not work. If the button isn't in an iframe it works. But I need the iframe to give page context. What's wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide an example webpage where this is happening? Please provide an easy-as-possible setup, with just the minimal functionality to reproduce this.

Comment: Sure, set up a simple test page. Problem is that you have to see the problem in fb iOS app webview window. [test page](http://cutyard.se/test/fb_iframe_stack.html)

Comment: @FredrikJohansson Did you find any solution to this? Does not work for me when using feed or share dialog.

Comment: @sricks no not really. If iframe and parent page is on same domain you could trigger the share function on parent page from the iframe page. If not on same domain you could use postmessage to do the same thing.